# Blender 2.78 cycles out of memory problem, in both cpu and gpu

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error, memory-management

I have a out of memory problem with Blender.

My specs are:
I am using Blender 2.78, Cycles
Intel I5 2400
Nvidia Gtx 750 ti 2GB
8 GB ram
Windows 7 64 bit

I can render simple stuff, but now when I’m starting to render a more complex scene of a couch I created and sculpted, it crashes and stops at 0%. with the error message 'ran out of memory' error.

It happens in both CPU and GPU rendering.

I tried reinstalling Blender, and also tried resetting to  factory settings, but it didn’t help.

Any idea?

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: possible: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/76068/2217

Comment: "*Any idea?*" Yeah it *'ran out of memory'* means you scene is too complex for your hardware. Either too much geometry or too big textures, impossible to know without looking at your scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sculpted, there's a high chance your face count is extremely high, and 8GB is not really that much ram. You can try to decimate the mesh (decimate modifier) and see if it will stop crashing and render with a lower poly count.

This will probably not be the accepted answer, but might help.

EDIT: If you are using subdivision, check that the view and render division levels are the same, since if you have a higher render number when you see it in the viewport its what you want, but when you render you get an exponential number of faces.

Comment: Thank you! Using the Decimate Modifier helped, I really did have alot of faces.

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 1):

For GPU: Dont' use progressive refine in the Render->performance settings. Use the tiles as big as possible but as small as necessary to not get this error.

Anyway if the problem is high poly count you might try a solution given here [Cycles memory problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26945/cycles-memory-problem?rq=1)