# How to free up ram using blender

Tags: modeling, rendering, memory-management

im trying to create animation with blender but it keep crashing due to ram limitation , i had to close blender (not responding) and reopen it then continue rendering , this happens before for, idk if im right or not but blender uses a weird "building bvh" which increases ram usage each frame i don't want it sir !

also when i open blender and do stuff it gradually increases ram usage when i hit f12 it crashes due to low ram , i had to save the file close blender , reopen blender open the file that i had changes on and then hit render it is hilarious .

is there any command or way to free all the garbage that blender stored in memory before hitting render ?

Comment: building BVH is basically blender building your scene for rendering. Can't render without it. How much ram do you have? Also have a look at these answers: [cycles render engine - Blender uses more ram than my pc has when rendering - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/209443/53447)

Comment: currently it is 8gb , i remember back then when i was rendering another animation i had same issue with bvh that i was able to disable in render settings that i can't find it right now , but the actual issue is if i close and reopen blender it will continue rendering ! i want to clean the ram after each frame or each time that i want to hit render the cleanup option from file menu does it a little bit but not actually what i want , it seems like to be problem they even made lots of memes about it

Comment: There is no such thing as disabling BVH, but there are options that use [less memory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/performance.html), especially for CPU rendering.  Like smaller tile sizes, disabling spacial splits and persistent data, enable compact BVH, ... Now if you have memory usage increasing for no real reason, that might be a bug to report via Help > Report a bug.

Comment: @L0Lock believe me my friend there are tons of memory leak Bug reports in blender devtalk forums , for me it is obvious that blender is eating up memory for no reason , im just digging to find a way to cleanup memory manually instead of reopening the crashed blender

Comment: The devtalk forum is just that: a forum, not where bug reports are made. That would be on [projects.blender.org](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender), but definitely use the Help > Report A Bug menu so that it directly opens the bug report form prefilled with some info.